# visual studio 2015 ssrs preview report no working

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using VS 2015 with SSDT 2015. While I am creating an rdl report, the preview in VS is not working. I have checked the Data Source - everything is good with all credentials saved but still preview in VS is not working.

Why isn't the Preview working?

Comment: You are going to need to provide any information (preferably as much as possible) about your project or there is no way anyone can help you with this. You basically just repeated your post title 3 times and didn't ask a question...

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to Preview the report? What happens when you preview?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before.

it could be due to memory issues.

Anyway, I resolved that by closing everything, restarting the computer, and deleting cached data file